# WP7 to Android, is there an Isolated Storage analog on Android?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

Is there an analog of WP7 Isolated Storage in Android platform, or can Isolated Storage be emulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite certain about the details of WP7 isolated storage, but Android does provide a private file I/O mode for applications. Please do check [`openFileOutput`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), `openFileInput` and `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` in particular.

Comment: It's limited? For example 10Mb per application? It's "isolated"? For example i created file 'somefile.txt' in app A, could app B read it? Can i hide file from other apps?